# Values method in lodash not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I am building a react app with redux. The state managed by redux is an object of objects. I wanted to iterate through an object from the state and render it using map. So i used _.values from lodash to get an array of objects(because the object i want to render is an object of objects too). But the values method didn't return   an array with all my objects, instead it returned an array with length of 1 contains the whole object.
   This is the app component:

```
const App = () => {
  const { contacts } = store.getState();
  console.log(_.values(contacts))
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Sidebar contacts={_.values(contacts)} />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the reducer:

```
import { contacts } from "../static_data";
export default (state = { contacts }, action) => {
    return state;
};
```

and this this is the result of the console.log of _.values(contacts):

```
[{…}]
0
:
{ryg93t2eQ: {…}, rkel52Fhem: {…}, S1-xchK3gX: {…}, HkMg53Khgm: {…}, r1QxqnFhgX: {…}, …}
length
:
1
```

Comment: What does `console.log(contacts)` show?

Comment: @Barmar it's in the question dude, it shows an array with length of 1, contains an object of the objects that i want to render.

Comment: That's `console.log(_.values(contacts))`, not `console.log(contacts)`.

Comment: You probably want `_.values(contacts.someProperty)` and the property name will be shown in `console.log(contacts)`

Comment: @Barmar aaa sorry, yeah, it's an object of objects!

Comment: And what is the property that contains the object you want?

Comment: @Barmar All the propreties

Comment: Since you're getting an array of one element, there must be only one property.

Comment: @Barmar No, it works the first time when the state didn't pass through reducers, but the reducers get involved, the values method didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the object wrapped around contacts in the reducer. I’ve removed it below:

```
import { contacts } from "../static_data";
export default (state = contacts, action) => {
    return state;
};
```